# CSP ssue with Jhipster App deployed in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: angular, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster, content-security-policy

My app is quite straight forward Jhispter (with **Angular**) application, that uses `mapbox` and g`oogle fonts` as external libraries.
I simply deployed it to **Elastic Beanstalk**.
I googled and found some answers that I should only change the meta-data tag in my `index.html` file to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

But it did not work.

I also enabled it in the properties file, but seems with no impcat.

```
  cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: "*"
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers: "Link,X-Total-Count"
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

[image]

Comment: Those are CSP errors, not CORS errors

Comment: Fixed thanks, should this be fixed server side or  client side,  I am not good web developer

Comment: Check the `SecurityConfiguration.java` file. Around Jhipster 5.0.x, the property CSP headers is added to security configuration. As you can see real locks is performed by not your CSP, hence somewhere is published another one. It should be smthng like `.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self';")` there.

Comment: thanks @granty. I found `.contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")` should i remove it completeley to enable all CSP?

Comment: You can manage CSP via this `SecurityConfiguration.java` file - CSP will be delivered with HTTP header (it's a preferred way). If you comment/remove CSP lines in above file, you'll able to publish CSP via meta tag. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is also a challenging web security like [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

In **Jhipster**, it is configured in Spring boot, so I had to allow some trusted urls and changed my CSR configuration to:

```
.contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.mapbox.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: *.amazonaws.com; font-src 'self' data:")
```

This answer is based no the very helpful comments above